# Is there a standard of naming the domain for a XMPP server?

Tags: internet, domain, xmpp

I have a running XMPP server that's (sub)domain is set to `xmpp.domain.tld`.

Should i change it's domain so it has the same address as my mail (`domain.tld`)?

Is this bad style you shouldn't do, because the problem is that you can't see that it's an XMPP account or better because everybody would have a single ID for internet communications?

Accountname differences:

`username@xmpp.domain.tld`
vs
`username@domain.tld`

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is a standard for naming the domain name. Technically it’s not necessary, because the relevant information is saved in the DNS records ([i.e.](https://serverfault.com/q/582106/131794), `_xmpp-client._tcp` and `_xmpp-server._tcp`), so it’s only a usability question.

I think it makes more sense to use `username@example.com` for both, your JID and your email address. That way you, you only need to tell your people one address (and they only have to remember one) and mention that they can reach you via XMPP and/or email.

On the Web, you can specify which channel to use, by linking to the full URIs, e.g.,

```html
<a href="xmpp:username@example.com">…</a>
<a href="mailto:username@example.com">…</a>
```

Of course people might still confuse it (especially those that consider anything with a `@` to be an email address), but thanks to offering both channels under the same address, their message will not be lost.